# How to reconfigure log4j2 at runtime with new xml file

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 in a Web Application (servlet 3.0 API)

Log4j2 is configuring itself automatically when the application is started using a **log4j2.xml** file inside the WEB-INF directory.

When the context is started I execute some logic that produce some logs, and all the log produced are working accordingly to the rules defined in the **log4j2.xml** file.

At the end of my initialization logic I call a service that gives to me one or more log4j2 xml configuration files (for example, **config1.xml**, **config2.xml** and **config3.xml**).

Now I want to 'reconfigure' log4j using my initial **log4j2.xml** file together with all the new configuration files.

I cannot find a way to do this; I can find only a way to add programmatically new Appenders, new Loggers and so on;

I'd like to tell log4j2 "hey, here are some new configuration files; please, parse them and update your configuration accordingly"

There is a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Please check if "Composite Configuration" as described in the manual [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) works.

Comment: Unfortunately, that dosn't work. This is because the Composite Configuration can be used to specify more than one configuration file - and that's ok, but I need something more: I need to configure Log4j2 a second time, after the initial configuration happened... and I cannot find any API to do this

Comment: Chcek if the following helps.
 
`code` ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).reconfigure();

Comment: Great!! It works.

I've changed a bit the code to avoid the cast, using directly the org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggingContext API.
I will responde to my question, pointing to your comments! ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Vionixt comment to my question, I solved the problem.

The code I used was:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "<configFile1>,<configFile2>,<configFile3>");
LoggerContext.getContext(false).reconfigure();
```

where LoggerContext is

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggingContext
```

After reconfiguration, all the new Logging rules were available and also used!

thank you so much,
cheers

Comment: How did you reload your new configurations?